# Ubuntu Server - can't connect to github

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github

I am unable to use github from the command line on a newly installed Ubuntu server. Pinging and curling github fails but works fine for other hosts.

OS: `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`

#### Ping test

```bash
# google works fine
ping -c3 google.com
...
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms

# github fails - each ping attempt results in 'Destination Host Unreachable'
ping -c3 github.com
...
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2051ms
```

#### curl test

```bash
# google works fine
curl -s --head --request GET google.com > /dev/null; echo $?
0

# github fails
curl -s --head --request GET github.com > /dev/null; echo $?
7
```

#### git clone test

```bash
# fails with 'no route to host'
git clone https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole.git
Cloning into 'pi-hole'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 18534 ms: No route to host
```

I am not, to my knowledge, dealing with any proxies or abnormal firewall setup.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I had a fresh install of `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` and encountered the same issue.

It turned out my IP4 Gateway wasn't set, `nmcli d show | grep IP4.GATEWAY` yielded '--' results.

I've set it with `sudo ip route add default via 192.168.X.Y` and then I could clone with success.

I hope this helps :)